# Get tags for an article

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, tags

How can I query the db for all the tags associated with an article?

I have been able to use `JTable` to query to `*_tags` table, but that doesn't return the tags that are associated with the article record.

I'm interesting in something like:

```
$tags = JTags::searchByArticleId(1);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `TagsHelper::getItemTags()`:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\TagsHelper;

$tags = new TagsHelper;
$tags->getItemTags('com_content.article', $articleId);
```

Where `$articleId` is article ID. Tags will be available through `$tags->itemTags`.

If you already have article object loaded, you can add tags to it:

```
$article->tags = new TagsHelper;
$article->tags->getItemTags('com_content.article', $article->id);
```

Comment: I eventually stumbled on this, but nice to have it confirmed. Thank you.